# Why the difference in sats on Collaborative Connector Closures?

Tags: ark

According to https://www.arkpill.me/deep-dive, the value added to X is 240 sats when dealing with 1, 10 or 100 sats coins, but 280 sats when dealing with >100 sats coins.

Why?

[image]

Comment: The difference seems to have gone to the relay fee, but I don't understand myself why there would have to be a difference in relay fee, the txs seem identical in size.

Comment: Exactly. And to be honest, I don't know if 450 - 280 = 170 or if 450 - 170 = 280, the documentation is not clear.

Comment: Hi @StevenRoose, your comment looks like an answer to me (even though it’s short). Please don’t answer the question in comments, but make an answer post instead when you are answering the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in my comment, the difference in output value is because of a different relay fee for these transactions.

I don't however understand why these transactions would have a different relay fee value. It might be an oversight.